# Object Oriented Design Problem, Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: c++, oop

I'm making the design of a OO framework and I'm facing the following problem.

Let's say that in the framework I have a *Shape* interface and the users are free to implement and extends (adding new functions) the *Shape* interface to create their own figures, e.g. *Square* and *Circle*. To make these new objects available the users have to register them into a *ShapeFactory* specifying the name of the shape (string) and the object.

Furthermore, the framework provides an interface called *ShapeWorker* which defines the following function:

```
class ShapeWorker
{
public:
  void processShape( Shape& shape ) = 0;
};
```

The users are free to implement the *ShapeWorker* interface to make specific shape worker, e.g. *SquareWorker* and *CircleWorker*. To make these new objects available the users have to register them into a *WorkerFactory*, specifying the name of shape (string) and the object.

At a certain point, the framework, given a string representing the shape's name, creates a new *Shape*, by using the *ShapeFactory*, and afterwards (somewhere else in the code) creates a new *ShapeWorker*, by using the *WorkerFactory* with the same shape's name. The *processShape* is then called providing the *Shape* instance created before.

```
[ ... ]
Shape* myShape = shapeFactory.create( shapeName );
[ ... ]
ShapeWorker* myWorker = workerFactory.create( shapeName );
myWorker->processShape( *myShape );
[ ... ]
```

The point is that, doing so, I force the user implementing, for example, the *SquareWorker* to make a down-cast from *Shape* to *Square* into the *processShape* function so to access to the full *Square*'s interface:

```
class SquareWorker
{
public:
  void processShape( Shape& shape )
  {
     Square& square = dynamic_cast< Square& >( shape );
     // using Square interface
  }
};
```

This is against the Liskov substitution principle.

Now, is this approach wrong? What would it be the better solution? Note that I don't want to implement the processShape as *Shape*'s member function.

I hope the description has been clear enough.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Simo

Comment: You should add a C++ tag I think.

Comment: Can you provide the reasoning behind the statement "Note that I don't want to implement the processShape as Shape's member function"?

Comment: One of the problems here is that code with references to a Shape and a ShapeWorker has no idea whether it is safe to pass the Shape to the ShapeWorker, without some traceability back to the creation point to verify that both objects were created using the same shapeName.

Comment: Well the reason is the same of the Visitor patter: to separate the data structure from the algorithms. But the drawback of the Visitor patter is that the ShapeWorker should be aware of all the concrete Shapes (Square and Circle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your shapes have a common interface that must be used by the workers, this approach seems fully correct to me. A shape worker is more or less specialized on a specific shape, thus has knowledge about the class it handles. It would be nicer to do that using a common interface for all shapes but you cannot put everything you would need into it, it would end up fully cluttered. Downcasting is a correct mean to solve this.

The use of templates could help you out: you could create a base class for all workers

```
template <class T> 
class BaseShapeWorker : ShapeWorker
{
public:
  void processShape( Shape& shape )
  {
     T& specificShape = dynamic_cast< T& >( shape );
     processShape( specificShape )
  }
protected:
  virtual void processShape( T& shape ) = 0;
};
```

This would not need the implementers to know about this downcast and ease the implementation by maybe also providing some often reused functionality.

Comment: Thank you jdehaan, this is a great piece of advice! It would simplify the work for the implementers.